# how to split a string after a specific character?

Tags: python, split

I want to split a list of items with specific symbol.

I have used the following code

```py
data = "launch,  7:30am,  watch tv,  workout,  snap,  running,  research study and learn"
items = data.split(',')
print(', '.join([items[0], items[-1].split('—')[1]]))
```

Here what I wanted is that to split this data and print like this:

> launch, study and learn

but a problem appears when data changed like this:

```py
data = "launch, 7:30am, watch tv, workout, snap, running, research — discussion, study and learn"
items = data.split(',')
print(', '.join([items[0], items[-1].split('—')[1]]))
```

and in this I case I expected to get this result:

> launch, discussion, study and learn

as such, an error appears "list index out of range"! that is right because there is no symbol "-" after last element, because of "," and I instructed data to be splitted as "," therefore in "discussion, study and learn" will be treated as separate data so an error appears. I wanted to not rewrite any code, is it possible to use code reuse to read both data. is it possible to read after "-" symbol?

Comment: @hanan Is this correct ? ```' research' study and learn']``` Check your inverted comma.

Comment: @hanan bdw, Are you sure that your expected last element will be ```study and learn``` always?

Comment: @PySaad I mean ``study and learn`` words can change

Comment: @PySaad but exactly the last elements will be like that behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your expected output is dependent on word `research`

We can implement the same using regex which will search `research` word and gives you characters after it.

You can try this -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
(re.split(r'*research[^A-Za-z0-9]+',data))[-1]
#study and learn
#discussion, study and learn
```

Full Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
print ("{0}, {1}".format(data.split(',')[0], (re.split(r' *research[^A-Za-z0-9]+',data))[-1]))
#launch, study and learn
#launch, discussion, study and learn
```

Read more about python ***Regex*** :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

or about expressions here :

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: can I use the dash symbol `-` instead of `research`. additionally read after what follows the dash symbol `-` ?

Comment: @hanan Well, go ahead if that gives you expected result!

Comment: @hanan I see you have ascii character in your string. You can use this ```# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-``` at top of your script.  Check updated answer